# `member` returns `NIL` even though string exists in the list

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

Common Lisp.

I'm trying to determine if a string is present in a given list.

My goal is to have
 `(member searched-string my-list)`
but I keep getting `NIL`.

Why does `(member "foo" '("foo" "bar"))` return `NIL`?

[image]

Comment: btw., you are in a break loop -> you might want to leave that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because `(eql "foo" "foo") ; ==> nil`. While not documented in the CLHS [`member`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/lw51/CLHS/Body/f_mem_m.htm) uses `#'eql` as the standard test. To get it to use `#'equal` that also evaluates `t` for structures that display the same

```
(equal "foo" "foo") ; ==> t
(member "foo" '("foo" "bar") :test #'equal) ; ==> ("foo" "bar")
```

A string is stored as an vector of characters and thus unless it is the same object `eq` and `eql` will evaluate to `nil` while `equal` checks if all the characters in the strings are `eql`.

NB: `(eql "foo" "foo")` can also be `t`. Since it is literals and thus constant data the same code compiled will in some implementation only store `"test"` once so that they become pointer equal (`eq`).

Answer (score 8):

The default value for the `:test` keyword parameter is `#'eql`:

> If neither a `:test` nor a `:test-not` argument is supplied, it is as if a `:test` argument of `#'eql` was supplied.

[*17.2.1 Rules about Test Functions - Satisfying a Two-Argument Test*](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/17_ba.htm)

Strings are not numbers nor characters, so two strings are `eql` only if they are `eq` (identical), but in your example you probably have two different strings allocated. You could have optimizations where `string=` strings are interned by the compiler, making them `eq`, but that would be an implementation detail.

Here below, the same `foo` string is used to build the list, and as an argument to `member`, and the call actually find the value:

```
(let ((foo "foo"))
  (member foo (list foo "bar")))
=> ("foo" "bar")
```

But more generally, you want to pass a string comparison function, like `string-equal` (case-insensitive) or `string=` (exact case), or simply a general-purpose equality predicate; both examples below find the sarch string:

```
(member "foo" '("foo" "bar") :test #'equal)
(member "FOO" '("foo" "bar") :test #'equalp)
```

Comment: how would one find this, in CLHS? http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_mem_m.htm says nothing about this issue that I could find; it calls its argument "list", not "sequence"; `member` does not even appear in http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/c_sequen.htm...

Comment: I thought it would be linked from MEMBER, but there was no such link; then I look at the page for [FIND](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_find_.htm#find) and it was there, at the bottom. Yeah not very easy to find.